# Migrando a Genexus 17u8 problema con External Objetc en iOS

Tags: ios, genexus

estoy teniendo un problema con un External Object en iOS. Lo tenemos siguiendo los pasos segun la documentacion oficial de Gx(https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26936,HowTo%3A+create+an+External+Object+which+triggers+GeneXus+events+in+iOS)
Esto nos viene funcionando ok hasta la 17u4, ahora migrando a la 17u8 nos encontramos con este error al compilar, en el metodo  private func readParameter(index : Int) -> String? ...

[image: Codigo del EO]

El error tiene senido con lo que ahora se ve en la clase GxActionHandler.h:
[image: Definición de la clase GxActionHandler.h]

El tema es que hemos probado con varias opciones y en todas el metodo queda con error, alguna sugerencia? alguien se topo con este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones "readStringParameter" y "readParameter" fueron deprecadas en GeneXus v17 upgrade 6 y upgrade 7 respectivamente.

Te dejo documentación con mas información al respecto:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48112,iOS%20Flexible%20Client%20Deprecations

Ademas en este link a github, podes ver referencias de implementacion:

https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample/blob/master/SampleLibrary/iOS/BasicExternalObject.swift

Comment: Escpectacular, muchas gracias, ahora si, siguiendo esa referencia de implementacion, agarro viaje. Gracias!